# Google Chrome prevents some file downloads (.rpm)

Tags: chrome

Using Google Chrome on a fresh Fedora 36 install, with 3rd party repo for google-chrome enabled.

Trying to download a .rpm file, eg https://github.com/TheAssassin/AppImageLauncher/releases
Chrome window darkens a little for a few seconds, then comes back to regular state. Nothing happens. Downloading other files works. Downloading .rpm from Firefox works.

What I tried:

```bsh
mkdir -p /etc/opt/chrome/policies/managed/
in /etc/opt/chrome/policies/managed/00_gssapi.json added
"DownloadRestrictions": "0"
```

Restarted Chrome. No effect.

Answer (score 1):

One solution: `Security > Safe browsing > No protection`.
Would prefer something which simply allows specific file extensions to be downloaded.

Answer (score -4):

go to your chrome settings and disable file security

or just execute chrome with sudo (-99)

Comment: never ever execute a browser with sudo. That's just dangerous, and a non-solution. Please don't recommend that!

Comment: Ok, Safe Browsing > No protection worked, thanks.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I thought Chromium would drop privileges or refuse to run without `--no-sandbox`.